# How can I detect if an SVG contains a specific symbol?

Tags: svg, safari, symbols

I am using an svg file with symbols as follow:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
     <use xlink:href="aFile.svg#symbolName"/>
</svg>
```

Now I would like to know if the `"aFile.svg"` really contains the "symbolName" and simply raise an exception if not. For now, I did put an event `onload` on the `<use>` tag. When the `<use>` get loaded, I check the content's item size `getBoundingClientRect()`. If the size is greater than `0,0` it means we do have an item….

Everything was working fine until I tried on Safari. On Safari, I am getting a racing condition problem. The size of the `<use>` tag is not always ready when safari firesw `onload`. Which means that, sometimes I get the size, sometimes not (it is really random…). I temporarily fixed it using a `window.timeout(...)` but it is not the proper way to fix racing condition issues. So just to say, I am wondering if there is a cleaner way to achieve the same?

Comment: you could load it in an <object> tag and then call getElementById on the object's document.

Comment: May I ask what would you do if "aFile.svg" do not contains the "symbolName" ?

Comment: @enxaneta the real code displays a fallback content in the case the url is wrong or if the symbol is not found.

Comment: @RobertLongson I tried but the "object" does not have a getElementById. The document neither search into the object once it is loaded with the svg.

Comment: sure it does, although if you don't post what you've done I can't tell where you went wrong.

Comment: `xlink:href` is deprecated. You should use just `href` instead.

Comment: @RobertLongson okay I can get it using `.getSVGDocument()`. therefore: `object.getSVGDocument().getElementById("symbolName");`

Comment: @Anthony deprecated but `href` alone is still not supported on safari 12.0

Answer (score 0):

You probably cannot do this directly. If you first injected your file `aFile.svg` into the DOM you could simply use [`querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) to detect if the Symbol is available.

For injecting the SVG file this like may be useful: https://css-tricks.com/ajaxing-svg-sprite/